# Is there a way to refactor by adding an outer method call using Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this:

```
Arrays.asList(from(A, 14), from(A, 21), ...
```

What I need is:

```
Arrays.asList(of(from(A, 14), 1), of(from(A, 21), 2), ...
```

The call `from(A, number)` should be turned into `of(from(A, number), anotherNumber)`.

In other words: I have to update a lengthy list of such `from()` calls by enclosing them within an `of()` and adding a second parameter. Ideally, that second parameter would simply count upwards.

Is there a way to that with IntelliJ refactoring tools? 
( instead of doing it all manually )

And note: I am not asking for a tools recommendation. I am asking whether a known tool supports a specific refactoring situation.

Comment: I personally don't like statically importing common method names such as `of`. The method name by itself is meaningless in English. Also, it could easily be confused with `List.of`, `Stream.of`, `LocalDate.of`, etc.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException This is for a unit test, so context is very clear ... but I am already glad that I named the first static one "from", and not "of" of of of.

Answer (score 2):

You can highlight `from(` and use the "select next occurrence" hot key. Once you have selected all occurrences just replace it with `of(from`. Once you are done adding `of` you can use the "alt + left arrow key" to move the cursor to the position where you want to add the number OR use the "select next occurrence" by highlighting the `),`.

On Mac the hot key is "CTRL + G" and on Windows\Linux "ALT + J". Here is a list of the hot keys https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

It is still a bit manual, but beats doing it one by one.

Comment: That is definitely better than doing it all manual (like putting them in distinct rows, and use the column mode, what I did first).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

- **Extract method** with replacing the duplicates for `from(A, param)`
- Inside the extracted method write something like `of(from(A, param), NNN)`
- **Inline method**
- Replace `NNN` with numbers you need (this has to be performed manually)

If there is some formula that can calculate `anotherNumber` based on `number`, you can use it instead of `NNN`.

Answer (score 2):

"Replace structurally" can do some of what you need.

1. Select `Edit` > `Find` > `Replace Structurally...`
2. Enter `from($a$, $b$)` as the search template
3. Enter `of(from($a$, $b$), i)` as the replacement template
4. Choose `Scope`: `Current File` (or `Selection`, if you prefer)
5. Hit `Find`
6. Hit `Replace all`

Assuming `i` is undefined you'll then be left with lots of errors. You can cycle through the errors with `F2` and replace the undefined `i` with the values you want.

---

Bonus tip: on a Mac, run `seq 1 100 | pbcopy` at a terminal to put the numbers 1-100 into your clipboard. Then, with multiple cursors in IntelliJ, hit Paste. `1` will be pasted at the first cursor, `2` at the second, etc.